# jQuery form selector :input is excluding the :checked in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, jquery-selectors

Why is the :checked or input type checkbox is excluded? I am trying to select all the input using form selectors. It is working well in internet explorer but not in chrome or firefox. here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Using Form Selectors and Filters</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function() {
        $('form :input').css('border', '3px solid red');
    });
</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1{width: 600px;}
        .style2{width: 200px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Example Form Document</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">

        <table class="style1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">First Name</td>
                    <td><input id="FirstName" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td class="style2">Last Name</td><td>
                        <input id="LastName" type="text" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td class="style2">Disabled Text Field</td>
                    <td><input id="Text1" type="text" disabled="disabled"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td class="style2">Gender</td>
                    <td><input id="Male" type="radio" checked="checked"/>M<input id="Female" type="radio" />F</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">What products are you interested in?</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="Checkbox1">Widgets</label><br />
                        <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" /><label for="Checkbox1">Hibbity Jibbities</label><br />
                        <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="Checkbox1">SplashBangers</label><br />
                        <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" /><label for="Checkbox1">Whatzits</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                        
                    <td>
                        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /> <input id="Reset1" 
                            type="reset" value="reset" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can see that all inputs are being highlighted with red borders except those checkboxes. Can this be a browser or JavaScript issue? I am trying to learn jquery btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input type[checkbox] not accepting border property, maybe you can use
`Outline` or [1]: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/
for customize checkbox

Comment: thanks. it is working with outline but not with border. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work with borders?

Comment: Native browser form elements checkbox and radio are not allowing to customize, maybe you can hide the native appearance by`-moz-appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
-o-appearance:none;` then use custom checkbox styles [link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-checkbox-styles)